# ASP.NET Migration to Core (.NET 6.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

When migrating a view (.cshtml):

[image: code]

```cs
@{
  var attributesDanger = (object)new { @class = "text-danger" };
  var attributesLabel = (object)new { @class = "control-label" };
}
```

I got all these errors:

[image: errors]

> Invalid expression Term '='
> "class" is a reserved word an cannot be used in implicit expressions. An explicit expression("@()") must be used
> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Is there any syntax difference between .Net Framework and .Net Core that would cause these errors?

Comment: BTW, your `(object)`-casts shouldn't be necessary - I assume you're just passing `attributesDanger` and `attributesLabel` into the `htmlAttributes:` parameter of HTML-Helpers?

Comment: A comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647688/asp-net-core-5-error-class-is-a-reserved-word-and-cannot-be-used-in-implicit) suggests this is a low priority bug and offers a workaround (use `@@` instead of `@`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- As you're probably aware, C# (in `.cs` files) lets you use `@` as an identifier prefix to let you use C#'s reserved keywords as identifiers, e.g. `public class @float {}`.

  - Prior to ASP.NET Core (i.e. [ASP.NET MVC 1.x through 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51391202/159145)), the *HTML-Helpers* supported using C# *anonymously-typed* objects to specify HTML attribute names, including `@class` for HTML's `class=""` attribute:, e.g. `new { hidden = true, title = "tooltip text", @class = "foobar" }`
  - However, ASP.NET Core's Razor does not allow using `@` in `@class` here, even though it's still within a C# code-block. I don't know why this change was made in ASP.NET Core, but Razor's built-in support for HTML attributes and TagHelpers makes using anonymous-types (e.g. `new { attribName = "value" }`) somewhat obsolete.
- In Razor, the `@` character is *also* reserved to denote the start of a Razor *code-block* or render-expression; e.g.:

  - `<p>@paragraphText</p>`
  - `@{ await DoSomethingAsync(); }`
  - `@if( expr ) { <text>raw HTML here</text> }`
- Because Razor's parser is *[greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878387/what-is-greedy-token-parsing)* w.r.t. the `@` character, it means you need to escape the `@` when using `@` in literal output, such as in a CSS `@media`-query in an inline `<style>` element, or when putting an e-mail address in Razor HTML: e.g. `<a href="mailto:billg@@example.com">e-mail me</a>`.

  - As far as I can tell, since ASP.NET Core's own flavour of Razor launched you *also* need to escape `@` if it's used inside C# code within Razor code-blocks or render-expressions even though it isn't a literal.

---

...so change `@class` to `@@class`, like so:

(Also, you don't/shouldn't need the `(object)`-cast)

```
@{
  var attributesDanger = new { @@class = "text-danger" };
  var attributesLabel  = new { @@class = "control-label" };
}
```

However, as you're now using ASP.NET Core, you should avoid using the old HTML-Helpers and instead use Razor's built-in support for HTML attributes (this is independent of Tag-Helpers, btw):

```
<div class="@( someBool ? "text-danger" : "control-label" )"></div>
```

Or:

```
@{
    const String CLASS_DANGER = "text-danger";
    const String CLASS_LABEL  = "control-label";
    String cssClass = someBool ? CLASS_DANGER  : CLASS_LABEL;
}

<div class="@cssClass"></div>
```

Comment: This comment is so incredibly detailed and helpful tysm :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so try changing this:

`var attributesDanger = (object)new { @class = "text-danger" }`

to this:

`var attributesDanger = new { @class = 'text-danger' }`

i.e. remove `(object)` and use single quotes.

I don't really see where you did anything wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not change anything

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).